# Regex.Matches c# double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I got this code below that works for single quotes.
it finds all the words between the single quotes.
but how would I modify the regex to work with double quotes?

keywords is coming from a form post

so

```
keywords = 'peace "this world" would be "and then" some'


    // Match all quoted fields
    MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"'(.*?)'");

    // Copy groups to a string[] array
    string[] fields = new string[col.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        fields[i] = col[i].Groups[1].Value; // (Index 1 is the first group)
    }// Match all quoted fields
    MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"'(.*?)'");

    // Copy groups to a string[] array
    string[] fields = new string[col.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        fields[i] = col[i].Groups[1].Value; // (Index 1 is the first group)
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work to put the quotes in the string? @-strings use "" instead of \" for quotes. `@"""(.*?)"""`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You would simply replace the `'` with `\"` and remove the literal to reconstruct it properly.

```
MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(keywords, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
```

Comment: No need to escape `"` in regex.

Comment: prefect. and if I wanted to include the quotes in the string?

Comment: @user713813: Move the brackets (as well as the _nongreedy_ mark) to the respective ends of the string.

Comment: According to https://regex101.com/ it's necessary to use `""` in C#/.NET (two consecutive double quotes) to match a single double quote. Unlike Python for instance where you'd simply escape the double quote with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks for that modernization update @domjancik. When this was answered back in 2012, the backslash escape character was the preferred method. I think at the time the double quote only worked in VB.Net, and I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 13):

The exact same, but with double quotes in place of single quotes. Double quotes aren't special in a regex pattern. But I usually add something to make sure I'm not spanning accross multiple quoted strings in a single match, and to accomodate double-double quote escapes:

```
string pattern = @"""([^""]|"""")*""";
// or (same thing):
string pattern = "\"(^\"|\"\")*\"";
```

Which translates to the literal string

```
"(^"|"")*"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this regex:

```
"(.*?)"
```

or

```
"([^"]*)"
```

In C#:

```
var pattern = "\"(.*?)\"";
```

or

```
var pattern = "\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to match `"` or `'` ?

in which case you might want to do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    string input = "peace \"this world\" would be 'and then' some";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=([\'\""])).*?(?=\1)");
    Assert.AreEqual("this world", matches[0].Value);
    Assert.AreEqual("and then", matches[1].Value);
}
```