# Regular expressions: extract all words out of quotes

Tags: c#, regex, split

By using Regular Expressions how can I extract all text in double quotes, and all words out of quotes in such string:

```
01AB "SET 001" IN SET "BACK" 09SS 76 "01 IN" SET
```

First regular expression should extract all text inside double quotes like

```
SET 001
BACK
01 IN
```

Second expression shoud extract all other words in string

```
01AB
IN
SET
09SS
76
SET
```

For the first case works fine `("(.*?)")`. How can I extract all words out of quotes?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133220/regex-matches-c-sharp-double-quotes) its almost same as yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
(?:^|")([^"]*)(?:$|")
```

The groups matched by it will exclude the quotation marks, because they are enclosed in non-capturing parentheses `(?:` and `)`. Of course you need to escape the double-quotes for use in C# code.

If the target string starts and/or ends in a quoted value, this expression will match empty groups as well (for the initial and for the trailing quote).

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
\"[^\"]*\"
```

Use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for texts in double quotes, and use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5k3ak3e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for all other words:

```
var strInput = "01AB \"SET 001\" IN SET \"BACK\" 09SS 76 \"01 IN\" SET";
var otherWords = Regex.Split(strInput, "\"[^\"]*\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try replacing the words inside quotes with empty string like:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\".*?\"", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string p = "01AB \"SET 001\" IN SET \"BACK\" 09SS 76 \"01 IN\" SET";

        Console.Write(r.Replace(p, "").Replace("  "," "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to negate the pattern in your first expression.

(?!pattern)

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex).

Answer (score 1):

If suggest you need all blocks of sentence - quoted and not ones - then there is more simple way to separate source string by using Regex.**Split**:

```
static Regex QuotedTextRegex = new Regex(@"("".*?"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var result = QuotedTextRegex
                .Split(sourceString)
                .Select(v => new
                    {
                        value = v,
                        isQuoted = v.Length > 0 && v[0] == '\"'
                    });
```